# how to revert to original css values after .css() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element I am changing with an animation as follows:

```
that$.animate({
                    opacity:'0.0'
                },300,
                function() {
                    $('#menuHolder').css({
                        left:'0px',
                        top:'0px',
                        height:'100%',
                        width:'100%',
                    },0);
```

This is meant to make `menuHolder` take up the whole screen. When clicking a separate button, I want `menuHolder` to revert to the original values i assigned in the style sheet. Here is the code for the return button:

```
$('.return').bind('click',
        function() {
            $(this).hide(300);

            tMT$ = $(this).parent();

            tMT$.animate({
                opacity:'0.0'
            },300,
            function() {
                $('#menuHolder').css({
                    left:$(this).style.left,
                    top:$(this).style.top,
                    height:$(this).style.height,
                    width:$(this).style.width
                },0);
            })
```

This doesnt work, because I have assigned the original css values with when `that$.animate` was executed. How should I assign the values of `.return`'s click so that `menuHolder` reverts to its original css?

I don't want to manually reassign values. I would rather do it programmatically =D. Any help would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is why you *should not* change individual CSS properties from your jQuery/Javascript code. Other than not being elegant, readable and maintainable and not separating presentation from behaviour, it will lead to situations like yours.

**Instead:**

Create classes in your CSS file:

```
.full-screen { left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

and only use jQuery/Javascript to add/remove them:

```
$('#menuHolder').addClass('full-screen');
...
$('#menuHolder').removeClass('full-screen');
```

[jQuery Class Manipulation Methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the other answers.. BUT...

Sometimes adding css in the script is required. For example, when animating or setting dynamic css properties.

**Differences between .addClass() and .css()**

`.addClass()` actually adds a class and the CSS for it.

`.css()` adds the CSS to the tag

Example

```
<!-- default -->
<div></div>
<!-- added class -->
<div class="added-class"></div>
<!-- added css -->
<div style="height:100px"></div>
```

the way to change it back is to just leave the property empty.

```
$(selector).css('height','');
```

It will remove the style-property completely and output:

```
<!-- removed css -->
<div></div>
```

Comment: He is not doing animations (uses that "thing" in the callback), he is doing something that is a typical "use classes" scenario.

Comment: Yes I can see that from his code snippet, but I think this is still a correct answer to his question. Read my answer.. "sometimes... is required"... all I'm saying is that there is a way to completely remove the styles added by a script... and that was the actual question, right?

Comment: It is an answer, yes. It works. It is very rarely required, and I consider it bad practice. That is why I only added a comment and have taken no other action.

Comment: why do you consider it bad practice? just to get this right... i am really interested.

Comment: Because of separation of concerns. In Javascript, you set your item into a specific state that is required by the logic of your program. The visual description of that state belongs to the stylesheet. When your code gets a bit more complicated, you will see the benefits.

Comment: There are absolutely cases where you need to set values based on variable conditions such as browser width, scroll position, etc. This is a perfectly valid solution in those cases, and I see no reason for criticism.

Comment: This is a great explanation of what is the problem and what exactly is happening

Answer (score 3):

Best way to accomplish this is by adding a class, which you can remove when you want the revert the original CSS. This makes it also easier to maintain, all the CSS stays in your stylesheets.

```
$('#menuHolder').addClass('animate')
```

and

```
$('#menuHolder').removeClass('animate')
```

in your stylesheet:

```
.animate {
left:0px;
top:0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```